# Probability of at least one pair of n normalised random number has lenght r

Tags: probability

So here is my problem. Assume that $X=[x_1,x_2,..,x_n]$ where $x_i \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\,\sigma^{2})$ and $\mu=0$ and $\sigma=1$. $Y= \frac{X}{|X|}$ wthich means that $Y$ is a unit length $n$ dimensional vector.

I am interested in the probability that at least one pair from Y (e.g $y_1$ and $y_2$) has at least Euclidean length $r$ if viewed as a two dimensional vector.

First I considered one pair $y_a$ and $y_b$. I calculate probability of these to have length less then or equal to r using the following formula:

$P=\frac{\int_{-r}^{r}  \sqrt{2\cdot (\mathcal{N}(\mu,\,\sigma^{2}))^2}}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  \sqrt{2\cdot (\mathcal{N}(\mu,\,\sigma^{2}))^2}}$

Then I calcuate the probability of pair $y_a$ and $y_b$ being the only pair in the set with euclidean lenght at least r.

$P_{ab} = P\cdot  ({{n}\choose{2}} -1)\cdot (1-P)$

Then there is ${n}\choose{2}$ possible combinations so the final probability is given by $P_{ab}\cdot {{n}\choose{2}}$.

Now I am not sure at all whether any of these makes sense. But it is preatty sure that the normalization process is not incorporated into my solution and I have no idea how to do so. Can anybody help?

Comment: It might be worth a simulation to look at the largest magnitude $y_a$ and second largest magnitude $y_b$ and the corresponding distribution for $\sqrt{y_a^2+y_b^2}$ for some given $n$, just to get a feel for what is going on.

Comment: Your equation $P= \cdots$ does not make sense to me. I don't understand it.  In the first sentence, you use $x_i$ and then you write $X_i$ in capital letter. Finally, are the $X_i$'s (or the $x_i$'s as it's not clear to me) independent?

Comment: @user52227 you are right. I corrected the mistake. and yes $x_i$s are indemendently drawn form a normal distribution.

Comment: @DalekSupreme Just double checking: $Y$ is on a $n-1 $dimensional hypersphere embedded in $n$-dim, but you want the extrinsic Euclidean distance instead of the intrinsic distance?